# JSON Web Service over simple HTTP GET/POST

Tags: java, json, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

Can you suggest a way or a framework or etc. for Java EE in order to make simple HTTP GET/POST calls to some web services like in SOAP web services but transport format must be JSON; not XML and there must not be any wrapper around(may be some vey lightweight header) like SOAP etc.

In short, my purpose is to serve web services using JSON and HTTP Get/Post in a maximum possible lightweight solution.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite RESTful web services framework is [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/).

If you want the ability to support a SOAP service as well as a RESTful one, check out [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

Both of these frameworks support JSON, and either are suitable for both client side and server side applications.

Comment: Isn't SOAP considered RESTful?

Comment: Nope. http://www.taranfx.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Web Service can be as simple as a servlet that parses the JSON text data from the request, and outputs text in JSON format in the response.  JSON is a pretty simple format - you might not need a framework.

Comment: In fact this is of course possible via a servlet but, I seek for a simple framework for JSON. While writing a web service many facilities are provided (annotations etc. client server testing)by either framework or IDE but I know nothing similar for JSON...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/). Their documentation is very good and should have you writing REST services using JSON as transport very quickly.

---

Saw the date of the post just now oops...